# Can you play SEMI transparent WEBM videos in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I am using QT to build a custom component for QML. I want this component to be able to play a WEBM video that contains an alpha channel. However, all of my attempts have resulted in the transparent pixels of the video getting replaced with black ones. This is my code currently:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{

    m_pixmap = new QPixmap(1920, 1080); // Create a canvas to draw on:

    // Create something that can be drawn:
    m_painter = new QPainter(m_pixmap);
    m_rect = new QRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);

    // Create an area to present on:
    m_label = new QLabel();
    m_label->setPixmap(*m_pixmap);
    m_label->show();

    // Play video:
    m_videoSink = new QVideoSink();
    m_mediaPlayer = new QMediaPlayer();
    m_mediaPlayer->setVideoSink(m_videoSink);
    m_mediaPlayer->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("path..."));
    m_mediaPlayer->setLoops(QMediaPlayer::Infinite);
    m_mediaPlayer->play();

    // Add a an event for when the video frame changes:
    connect(m_videoSink, SIGNAL(videoFrameChanged(QVideoFrame)), this, SLOT(SetFrame(QVideoFrame)));

    qDebug() << "Constructed";
}

void MyClass::SetFrame(QVideoFrame frame)
{

    frame.paint(m_painter, *m_rect, m_options); //Stores the frame in the m_pixmap
    m_label->setPixmap(*m_pixmap);
}
```

In this example I attempt to use a `QMediaPlayer` to play the video, then a `QVideoSink` to extract the currently playing `QVideoFrame` and paint that to a `QPixmap` that is finally being displayed in a `QLabel`.

I have also tried to have the `QMediaPlayer` directly hooked up to a `QVideoWidget`.

I know that my WEBM video works as it is displaying as expected when imported in to other programs.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Qt 6 documentation, [`QVideoFrame::paint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvideoframe.html#paint) accepts a `QVideoFrame::PaintOptions` struct as an optional argument, which can be used to set things like background colors. Per your code it seems you've set one up, but I'm not sure what options you've set (if you've set any).